# How to change the text color of the title of Bootstrap-select?

Tags: bootstrap-select

For Bootstrap-Select, I want to change the text color of **title** to White with using the attribute  **data-style="btn-success"**.

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-success"  title="Choose one of the following...">
    <option>Mustard</option>
    <option>Ketchup</option>
    <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

Can anyone help? Thanks
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mclee/3f3uetvm/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi As i have understand your question i m trying to give you a simple solution for this. try to find below class

**.bootstrap-select.btn-group .dropdown-toggle .filter-option**

which you can find in your package inside **bootstrap-select.min** file and add color:#ffffff;

it will change dropdown list title color to white.

if you dont want to go inside min file then you can do this in your custom style.css but make sure you style.css file path should be down of bootstrap css files in head tag.

Hope it will help you

Comment: Thanks Tariq ! It works. What about the down arrow ? I want to change its color as well. Thanks

Comment: Solved in the same way. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Mac nice to know that you have fixed already. can you please vote for my answer. Thanks

Comment: Voted but not shown as I am new here and my reputation score is too low.